# How to place the number in the right place

Tags: python

```
def rightnumber(L):
    while i > 0:
        if L[i] < L[i - 1]:
            for j in L:
                if L[i] < L[j]:
                    L[i], L[j-1] = L[j-1], L[i]

        else:
            return
```

I'm not even close.. but I have no idea how to do this.
If there is a set of numbers like 1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 8 and I'm scanning the list to see where the 2 goes. How do I place it in the right spot then move everything to the right? 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8

Comment: Is this an exercise? Are you allowed to use more than just list indices and tuple unpacking?

Comment: It is an exercise. I believe so.

Comment: `i` is not defined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in function `insert`

```
# vowel list
vowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'u']

# 'o' is inserted at index 3
# the position of 'o' will be 4th
vowel.insert(3, 'o')

print('Updated List:', vowel)
```

Also if you can't use built-in functions, you can use the next trick:

```
vowel = vowel[:indexOfI+1] + ['o'] + vowel[indexofI+1:]
```

Comment: The question asked about moving elements.